# next-jdbc: execute multiple statements?

Tags: jdbc, clojure

I'm writing a simple database migration code in clojure using the new `seancorfield/next.jdbc` library.

How do I execute several SQL statements at once? The usecase is that I have a SQL file containing query code for migrating from one version to the next. `next.jdbc/execute!` only executes one statement as designed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether you can execute multiple statements in a single JDBC operation is database-dependent. Some databases allow multiple statements in a single operation, separated by a semicolon. If the JDBC driver supports it, `next.jdbc` will also support it.

If your JDBC driver does not support it, you'll need to make multiple `execute!` calls. Some databases allow you to wrap multiple DDL operations in a transaction (some of them ignore the transaction and commit each DDL operation separately anyway), some databases explicitly disallow a transaction around DDL operations.