# next:jdbc How to allow multiple statements for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc, clojure, clojure-next.jdbc

I want to run multiple statements on a single execution against SQL Server. I do it with Node.js but I cannot run the same query using next.jdbc

For example, if I run this:

```
(def db {:jdbcUrl "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/TESTDB;user=sa;password=passwd"})
(def ds (jdbc/get-datasource db))
(jdbc/execute! ds ["select * from EMPLOYEE;select FIRST_NAME from EMPLOYEE;"])
```

I have also tried to wrap the statement within a transaction with the same result

```
(jdbc/execute! ds ["BEGIN TRANSACTION select * from EMPLOYEE;select FIRST_NAME from EMPLOYEE; COMMIT"])
```

I always get the first query.

I have tried Microsoft's JDBC driver also.
Sean Corfield says that if the database supports it, then next.jdbc should support it. [next-jdbc: execute multiple statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468070/next-jdbc-execute-multiple-statements)

But I cannot make it work

---

**Solution**

As indicated by Sean Corfield

```
(jdbc/execute! ds ["BEGIN select * from EMPLOYEE;select FIRST_NAME from EMPLOYEE; END"] {:multi-rs true})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can run multiple statements and multiple result sets back but you have to tell `next.jdbc` that's the behavior you want.

Take a look at the tests for MS SQL Server running multiple statements: https://github.com/seancorfield/next-jdbc/blob/develop/test/next/jdbc_test.clj#L560-L572

This is mentioned (briefly) in the Getting Started guide: "If you pass the `:multi-rs true` option to `execute!`, you will get back a vector of results sets, instead of just one result set: a vector of zero or more vectors."

Comment: Your GitHub code snippet is not Java code.  You should add an actual reference showing JDBC being used with a statement or prepared statement in Java code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no part of this question involves the Java language. "next.jdbc" is a Clojure library and the question concerns how to extract multiple result sets from it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The OP posted Clojure code and specifically referred to the documentation I wrote about the library I maintain that he is trying to use!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SQL Server's JDBC driver does *not* support multiple statements.  But, even if it did, you should probably not be using it, as it opens a potential security hole for injection type attacks.  Instead, if you really need to execute multiple SQL statements, either refactor your current SQL into a single statement, or else use multiple statements wrapped in a single transaction.

For reference, some other JDBC drivers, such as MySQL, might support multiple statements.

Comment: Yes, MS SQL Server can run multiple statements via JDBC -- you just need BEGIN/END around them. You cannot run multiple statements via JDBC on MySQL as far as I know: you have to write a stored procedure for that. Several other databases allow for multiple statements in a stored procedure. PostgreSQL allows that but, unhelpfully, does not actually return multiple result sets from them.

Comment: @SeanCorfield [It is certainly possible to run multiple statements using JDBC with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797794/multiple-queries-executed-in-java-in-single-statement).

Comment: I didn't know about allowMultiQueries so, thank you!